# Smearing and charge balance for tungsten with interstitial oxygen in Quantum ESPRESSO

Tags: quantum-espresso, numerical-convergence, cell-optimization

What smearing would be ideal for a bcc W with interstitial O atom. I am running 3x3x3 unit cells with one N interstitial.
I am having convergence issues in `relax` and `vc-relax`, but not in `scf`. Could this be due to smearing? I have tried mv and cold. For an additional interstitial atom, should we change or consider charge differences? There aren't many examples of interstitial atom studies other than papers which don't mentioned anything in particular about these.

```
 &control
    calculation = 'vc-relax',
    etot_conv_thr =   1e-05
    forc_conv_thr =   1e-04
    tprnfor = .true.
    tstress = .true.
    verbosity = 'high'
    pseudo_dir = '.',
    !prefix='w',
 /
 &system
    ibrav = 1,
    celldm(1) = 18.000,
    nat = 55,
    ntyp= 2,
    ecutwfc = 50.0, ecutrho = 500.0,
    occupations='smearing', smearing='mv', degauss=0.01,
    !nbnd = 8,
    !nspin=2,
    starting_magnetization(1)= 0.6
 /
 &electrons
    mixing_beta = 0.7
    conv_thr=1e-6
 /
 &ions
    ion_dynamics='bfgs'
 /
 &cell
    cell_dynamics='bfgs'
    cell_dofree='volume'
 /
ATOMIC_SPECIES
 W 183.84 W.pbe-spn-rrkjus_psl.1.0.0.UPF
 O 15.999 O.pbe-n-rrkjus_psl.1.0.0.UPF
ATOMIC_POSITIONS crystal
W      0.000000   0.000000   0.000000
W      0.166667   0.166667   0.166667
W      0.000000   0.000000   0.333333
W      0.166667   0.166667   0.500000
W      0.000000   0.000000   0.666667
W      0.166667   0.166667   0.833333
W      0.000000   0.333333   0.000000
W      0.166667   0.500000   0.166667
W      0.000000   0.333333   0.333333
W      0.166667   0.500000   0.500000
W      0.000000   0.333333   0.666667
W      0.166667   0.500000   0.833333
W      0.000000   0.666667   0.000000
W      0.166667   0.833333   0.166667
W      0.000000   0.666667   0.333333
W      0.166667   0.833333   0.500000
W      0.000000   0.666667   0.666667
W      0.166667   0.833333   0.833333
W      0.333333   0.000000   0.000000
W      0.500000   0.166667   0.166667
W      0.333333   0.000000   0.333333
W      0.500000   0.166667   0.500000
W      0.333333   0.000000   0.666667
W      0.500000   0.166667   0.833333
W      0.333333   0.333333   0.000000
W      0.500000   0.500000   0.166667
W      0.333333   0.333333   0.333333
W      0.500000   0.500000   0.500000
W      0.333333   0.333333   0.666667
W      0.500000   0.500000   0.833333
W      0.333333   0.666667   0.000000
W      0.500000   0.833333   0.166667
W      0.333333   0.666667   0.333333
W      0.500000   0.833333   0.500000
W      0.333333   0.666667   0.666667
W      0.500000   0.833333   0.833333
W      0.666667   0.000000   0.000000
W      0.833333   0.166667   0.166667
W      0.666667   0.000000   0.333333
W      0.833333   0.166667   0.500000
W      0.666667   0.000000   0.666667
W      0.833333   0.166667   0.833333
W      0.666667   0.333333   0.000000
O      0.416666   0.500000   0.500000
W      0.833333   0.500000   0.166667
W      0.666667   0.333333   0.333333
W      0.833333   0.500000   0.500000
W      0.666667   0.333333   0.666667
W      0.833333   0.500000   0.833333
W      0.666667   0.666667   0.000000
W      0.833333   0.833333   0.166667
W      0.666667   0.666667   0.333333
W      0.833333   0.833333   0.500000
W      0.666667   0.666667   0.666667
W      0.833333   0.833333   0.833333
! this is a comment that the code will ignore
K_POINTS automatic
4 4 4 1 1 1
```

Comment: I don't know much about QE, but W psuedopotentials tend to be difficult (in my experience).  You may need more valence electrons to stabilize your calculation maybe?

Comment: For studying effects due to an interstitial atom, I'm not sure as to why you've chosen a vc-relax calculation. Usually, the unit cell of the unaltered crystal will be subjected to vc-relax and with the optimized unit-cell parameters you would construct the supercell. Include the interstitial atom and then do a "relax calculation". Atleast this is how I've seen it being done.

Comment: Since youre having convergence issues, could you try to change the default diagonalization form "david" to "cg" using diagonalization = "cg" in your &electrons namelist. It has helped me sometimes atleast.

Comment: @TristanMaxson I will check that.

Comment: @AnoopANair namaskaram, and thank you so much. My end intention is to perform an NEB calculation, and assumed that i should relax the interstitial embedded cell to start the NEB. I didn't recognise the need to relax pure cell before interstitial addition, but that seems obvious now. Thank you for that input. I will check that, and also diagonalization.

Comment: @Dr.Viper I think his main point was that you should relax the pure cell before addition, but also keep it fixed after addition.  This assumes you want to model the dopant in its non-interacting dilute limit rather than relaxing the crystal to account for the dopant being incorporated uniformly.  Think of surface calculations where the cell dimensions do not change, even after absorption of an adsorbate if this helps you think about it.  The adsorbate in high coverage may play a slight role in the surface cell, but in the dilute limit it should definitely not influence things.

Comment: @TristanMaxson thank you so much for clarifying. For extra valence electrons, do i need to find a new potential or use some other all-electron code like Wien2k?

Comment: @Dr.Viper Scratch my suggestion, you already are using a spn potential which means s and p states are involved as valence.

Comment: @Dr.Viper though there is a lot of reason for not converging you can try to change your k point grid and see if it improves the performance.

Comment: @ShafayetRahat, thank you for your comment. Do you mean increasing the number of k-points to improve convergence or reduce to improve performance?

Comment: @AnoopANair I tried cg diagonalization as well as the relax after vc-relax of free cell, but same issue. Just after the first iteration, the estimated accuracy goes to very large values, and no convergence in the end. Any thoughts? Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @Dr.Viper Yeah, I meant that.

Comment: @Dr.Viper Namaskaram und! :). Sorry for the late reply! Could you upload the output file into your GitHub account and keep the link on your question. It will improve your chances of getting an answer!

Comment: @Dr.Viper I think you need to upload the output file in order to help get an answer from this community. The `code block` (like the one you used to show us your input file) should allow you to include a few thousand lines, but if it's too big to put in a `code block` here, then please upload it here: https://github.com/HPQC-LABS/Modeling_Matters in a folder called 4026, as you can see from the URL of this question that this is post #4026. Otherwise we'll have to close the question as "abandoned".

Comment: @NikeDattani added to a forked git - https://github.com/blushark/Modeling_Matters/tree/master/4026 as I have no write access to the folders you shared.

Comment: @AnoopANair The output file is now merged into the Master Branch on GitHub: https://github.com/HPQC-LABS/Modeling_Matters/tree/master/4026. Also Dr.Viper, thanks for uploading the output file. I've also given you permission to join the group so that you don't have to continue to maintain a fork of the repository if you want to add something more in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many reasons behind not converging. Sometimes structure doesn't converge if you describe them wrong. So, in my opinion, the best way to converge a structure is to study it clearly. Moreover, this convergence also varies for observing different properties too.
One common trick is to check smearing in your system.
For your system check if it converges for "gaussian" or any other smearing.
Another reason for not converging is the lack of an appropriate k point mesh grid for your system. Increasing the K point mesh grid may improve the convergence in less iteration though it consumes more computing time. You need to be careful choosing the k point mesh grid if it supports your system. Another thing you can do is to increase iteration from default. Also, you can change the pseudopotential type.